# Photo Competition 2022-02-28: Cross-section

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Cross-section

A piece of fruit cut in half, the inside of a model, the end of a building under construction, where the end wall is missing, ...

This theme was suggested by [spikey_richie](//photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/94572/).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128742/photo-competition-2022-02-28-cross-section?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on March 14, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Baguette

[image: Baguette]

Just finished lunch, remembered the contest, looked down on the table, ran to grab the camera. Hoping it makes you hungry.

```
Canon EOS 70D
Canon EF-S 35mm Macro
ISO 1250 
f/9
1/60s
RawTherapee+Gimp.  

Paris, 2022.03.01
CC-BY-SA
```

Answer (score 6):

## NZ Tree fern in cross section

[image: NZ Tree fern]

 Seen on Tiritiri Matangi, New Zealand

 Panasonic Lumix GX80

 f:4

 ss:1/25th

 51mm

ISO:1600

Answer (score 2):

**Astronomy Tower**

[image: Astronomy Tower]

A model of the astronomy tower featured in Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Price. Taken at the Warner Bros studio tour in London, UK.

OMD E10 MK 3 with a 25mm Lumix prime lens
ƒ/1.7, 1/100, 25 mm, ISO1600