# Photo Competition 2022-03-14: Freezing or Melting

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Freezing or Melting

Anything that is frozen or melting, literally or metaphorically. Examples include anything to do with snow/ice, movement that is frozen, something that is "frozen through time", a chocolate or candle melting, or someone having a meltdown.

This theme was suggested by [whackamadoodle3000](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/97631/).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128742/photo-competition-2022-02-28-cross-section?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on March 28, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

**Previous contest:** [2022-02-28: Cross-section](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128742/)
**Next contest:** [2022-03-28: Famous Buildings](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128968/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Frost Flower**
[image: FrostFlower]
Nikon D7000 & 18-140mm lens, 105mm, f/9, 1/160 s, ISO 200 
3 Jan 2018

During a cold spell (a few degrees below freezing), the plant Verbesinia virginica (common name: Frostweed) in my backyard supported delicate frost flowers (water exuding from the split stem of the plant which freezes upon contact with the cold air) creating many interesting forms. This was a photographer's nightmare as there were hundreds of beautiful "flowers" to photograph.

Answer (score 5):

**Blades of grass**

Olympus E-M10 Mark III
ƒ/2.8
1/400
60 mm
ISO800

I had to get right down for this one. It was taken at around 10am on a cold January, here in the UK. No post, straight out of the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Ice on ice**
[image]
Canon 5D Mark III, Canon 100-400 II at 400mm, F9, 1/125, ISO 100
January, 2017
Just saw this one cold morning in one lake in Dusseldorf.

Answer (score 3):

**Juda Ka Talab** a frozen Lake in the mighty Himalayas of Uttarakhand, India.

[image]

Date of capture **:** Dec 23, 2019

Answer (score 3):

**Frozen Mahonia**

Olympus E-M10 Mark III
ƒ/2.8
1/640
60 mm
ISO800

I took this on the first day my 60mm macro lens arrived before I got used to how it works properly. Not bad for a first attempt. No post, straight out of the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Frozen Canal**

[image: Frozen Canal]

Taken during Peak winter at Amsterdam.

Camera: **Nikon D40**
ƒ/5.6 1/100 55mm ISO400

Answer (score 2):

### **Icicles frozen on a branch**

[image]

iPhone X, 28mm, f1.8, ISO 100, 1/60s

St. Marys, PA January 3, 2022

In the bottom right corner you can see water flowing. This water was splashing up onto a branch and freezing there as icicles.

Answer (score 2):

**Icy moss & fungi**

Olympus E-M10 Mark III
ƒ/4
1/125
60 mm
ISO640

I took this and a series of photos whilst on a local woodland walk, the day after I got my new macro lens. The light was poor, but I'm pleased with how this came out. No post, straight out of the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Frozen Puddle**

[image: Frozen Puddle]

Wahner Heide near Cologne/Germany, Feb 1991

Canon EOS 620, Fujichrome, "scanned" using Canon EOS-M

A frozen puddle, beginning to melt in the sunlight.

(remembered that image from my recent scanning session)